# Indices of multiple elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and a list as follows

```
y=np.array([[1],[2],[1],[3],[1],[3],[2],[2]])
x=[1,2,3]
```

I would like to return a tuple of arrays each of which contains the indices of each element of x in y.
i.e.

```
(array([[0,2,4]]),array([[1,6,7]]),array([[3,5]]))
```

Is this possible to be done in a vectorized fashion(without any loops)?

Comment: Are all elements from `x` guaranteed to be in `y`?

Comment: yes all the elements in  `x` are guaranteed to be in `y`

Comment: Just to see the parameters involved - What's the  typical length of `y` and `x` in your actual use case?

Comment: Since the resulting lists can differ in size it's unlikely that there's a 'vectorized' solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
y = y.flatten()
[np.where(y == searchval)[0] for searchval in x]
```

Comment: Can't avoid the for loop,can I?

Comment: Nope, that's really not possible. This should be fast however.

Comment: map uses an internal for loop anyways, so I suspect this is faster

Comment: There isn't a significant speed difference between `map` and list comprehension.  Neither moves the call to `where` to C code.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to `map`

```
y = y.reshape(1,len(y))
map(lambda k: np.where(y==k)[-1], x)

[array([0, 2, 4]), 
 array([1, 6, 7]), 
 array([3, 5])]
```

---

Reasonable performance. For 100000 rows,

```
%timeit list(map(lambda k: np.where(y==k), x))
3.1 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this small example, a dictionary approach is actually faster (then the `wheres):

```
dd = {i:[] for i in [1,2,3]}
for i,v in enumerate(y):
   v=v[0]
   if v in dd:
       dd[v].append(i)
list(dd.values())
```

This problem has come up in other SO questions.  Alternatives using `unique` and `sort` have been proposed, but they are more complex and harder to recreate - and not necessarily faster.

It's not a ideal problem for `numpy`.  The result is a list of arrays or lists of differing size, which is a pretty good clue that a simple 'vectorized' whole-array solution is not possible.  If speed is an important enough issue you may need to look at `numba` or `cython` implementations.

Different methods could have different relative times depending on the mix of values.  Few unique values, but long sublists might favor methods that use repeated `where`.  Many unique values with short sublists might favor an approach that iterates on `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` followed by a comprehension:

```
y = np.array([[1],[2],[1],[3],[1],[3],[2],[2]])
x = [1,2,3]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate(y.flat):
    d[item].append(idx)

res = tuple(np.array(d[k]) for k in x)

(array([0, 2, 4]), array([1, 6, 7]), array([3, 5]))
```

Comment: I first used `defaultdict`, but realized that with a known `x` list, a regular dictionary  worked just as well, and possibly was a faster.

Comment: @hpaulj, I'm sure you're right. The only issue I have with your solution is `dd.values()` is only ordered in Python 3.6+.